# Why does the Torah repeat itself in Matos?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, mattos

[במדבר לא יא](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.31.11?lang=bi&aliyot=0) says:

> וַיִּקְחוּ֙ **אֶת־כׇּל־הַשָּׁלָ֔ל וְאֵ֖ת כׇּל־הַמַּלְק֑וֹחַ בָּאָדָ֖ם וּבַבְּהֵמָֽה**
>
> They gathered all the spoil and all the booty, man and beast,

[במדבר לא יב](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.31.12?lang=bi&aliyot=0) says:

> וַיָּבִ֡אוּ אֶל־מֹשֶׁה֩ וְאֶל־אֶלְעָזָ֨ר הַכֹּהֵ֜ן וְאֶל־עֲדַ֣ת בְּנֵֽי־יִשְׂרָאֵ֗ל **אֶת־הַשְּׁבִ֧י וְאֶת־הַמַּלְק֛וֹחַ וְאֶת־הַשָּׁלָ֖ל** אֶל־הַֽמַּחֲנֶ֑ה אֶל־עַֽרְבֹ֣ת מוֹאָ֔ב אֲשֶׁ֖ר עַל־יַרְדֵּ֥ן יְרֵחֽוֹ
>
> and they brought the captives, the booty, and the spoil to Moses, Eleazar the priest, and the whole Israelite community, at the camp in the steppes of Moab, at the Jordan near Jericho.

Why couldn't the Torah just write:
וַיִּקְחוּ֙ אֶת־כׇּל־הַשָּׁלָ֔ל וְאֵ֖ת כׇּל־הַמַּלְק֑וֹחַ בָּאָדָ֖ם וּבַבְּהֵמָֽה וַיָּבִ֡אוּ אֶל־מֹשֶׁה֩ וְאֶל־אֶלְעָזָ֨ר הַכֹּהֵ֜ן וְאֶל־עֲדַ֣ת בְּנֵֽי־יִשְׂרָאֵ֗ל אֶל־הַֽמַּחֲנֶ֑ה אֶל־עַֽרְבֹ֣ת מוֹאָ֔ב אֲשֶׁ֖ר עַל־יַרְדֵּ֥ן יְרֵחֽוֹ?

Comment: I think that [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UQAIk2Z-nubmO-b4ULEhNrezL4dteGFs/view?usp=sharing) may answer it, but I don't understand what it is saying.

Answer (score 0):

That link you mentioned does sound like it may be an answer. What I was able to understand is that they brought it all to Moshe to ask him what God wants them to do with it.

And perhaps אפשר לומר, about the reason it repeats itself and in separate verses is to emphasize the fact that they brought it all straight to Moshe. As a *Shvach*: They did not hide anything for themselves.

The way you phrased the possible fusion of both verses makes it possible to interpret the verse as though they did not necessarily bring all the spoils to Moshe right away, but stopped at their houses/tents/teepee and stored some booty away for themselves.

[Did try to post this as a comment but it was too long.]